# Problema de conexão DBDesigner 4 + MySQL

Tags: mysql

Não estou conseguindo conectar a ferramenta `DBDesigner` com o `MySQL`. Quando tento conectar aparece a mensagem:

> dbExpress: Invalid Username/password

Encontrei em alguns fóruns a sugestão de digitar no prompt do MySql o seguinte comando `"mysql>SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'host' = OLD_PASSWORD('password');"`

Tentei e recebo mensagem de erro:

> ERROR 1372 (HY000): PASSWORD hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Tens o endereço do `host` bem configurado? E o teu `host` aceita ligações a partir do IP de onde te estás a ligar?